# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') - Not an issue with DOM ordering

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Like the the 10,000 examples with the exact same heading, I am having a trouble with the development of a chrome extension, specifically the execution of scripts between my popup window and my content script.

The specific error i'm receiving is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')".

Now, I have reviewed several dozen threads with the same issue and the common theme seems to be that the placement of the scripting within the HTML code is causing the script to execute prior to the DOM loading, however I have attempted the following to resolve placement being an issue.

I have reviewed my code and I have ensured that the script it executing directly above the  tag (as to be the last item executing within the body section, and that the code also has the 'delay' flag within the script has a redundancy. I have also wrapped the code within the content script in window.onload=function() as a further redundancy, but alas, no love. I have also attempted moving the order of the code around within foreground.js, however as expected that didn't resolve the issue.

**foreground.js**

```
function calculatescript() {
    console.log("This prints to the console of the page")
    }; 

window.onload=function(){
    var runcalculate = document.getElementById("runcalculate");
    runcalculate.addEventListener("click", calculatescript);
    }
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    <title>Example Extension</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button class="button button1" id="runcalculate">Calculate</button>
    </div>

    <script src="foreground.js" defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.js**

```
{

    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Example",
    "description": "An example of a chrome extension using manifest v3",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo/logo-16.png",
        "48": "logo/logo-48.png",
        "128": "logo/logo-128.png"
    },
    "options_page": "settings/settings.html",
    "action": {
        "default_title": "example",
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "scripting"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["foreground.js"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }]
}
```

A background js scripts exist however are empty.

If I remove the attempt to pass the script and print directly to the console without trying to wrap it in a button, it works without issue.

I've exhausted my knowledge of what to do to get this working, and the ability to execute off a button is I imagine a fairly common practice, so I'm **obviously** doing something inherently wrong.

Comment: The popup is a different page so you can't load the same script there and in the content_scripts. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: I agree that it sure looks like it boils down to what `document` refers to, but the popup page does import the script.

Comment: It's not about importing the script. The script should only run in the page it's designed for, and this script is designed for the popup page. For web pages you need to use a different content script that is designed to work on the web pages and you won't load it in the popup. Depending on the actual goal, the solution may be as simple as removing `content_scripts` from manifest.json and using the correct devtools for the popup.

Comment: My loose understanding is that only the content script loaded within the manifest.js file can access the dom. So while in this instance it is potentially possible to run the script from popular.html, it wouldn't assist me with my subsequent intent of pulling information from DOM elements